# java - generate unicode pdf with Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, utf-8, pdfbox

I have to generate pdf in my spring mvc application. recently I tested [iTextPdf library](http://itextpdf.com/), but i could not generate unicode pdf document. in fact I didn't see non-latin characters in the generated document. I decided to use Apache PDFBox for my purpose, but I don't know has it support unicode characters? If has, is there any good tutorial for learning pdfBox? And If not, which library should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both iText and PDFBox can be used to print characters beyond Latin ones if used properly. As @Tilman answered, an easy way has been introduced in PDFBox only recently. IText also allows an easy way. If you happen to not only mean non-Latin but also non-LTR, you probably should tell.

Comment: I need to use both Latin and non-Latin(for example Persian) characters in one document. In fact, my page has both LTR and RTL texts.

Comment: I'm afraid that should be added to the question. Often people only think of very special variations of certain Latin characters, or of Cyrillic or Dingbats in this context. Characters requiring special ligatures and RTL are not necessarily on their minds.

Comment: Why would you claim that iText doesn't support unicode? That's not true, so please adapt your question.

Answer (score 5):

The 1.8.* versions don't support PDF generation with Unicode, but the 2.0.* versions do. This is the example EmbeddedFonts.java:

```
public class EmbeddedFonts
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);

        String dir = "../pdfbox/src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/ttf/";
        PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File(dir + "LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"));

        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        stream.beginText();
        stream.setFont(font, 12);
        stream.setLeading(12 * 1.2);

        stream.newLineAtOffset(50, 600);
        stream.showText("PDFBox Unicode with Embedded TrueType Font");
        stream.newLine();

        stream.showText("Supports full Unicode text ?");
        stream.newLine();

        stream.showText("English русский язык Tiếng Việt");

        stream.endText();
        stream.close();

        document.save("example.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Note that unlike iText, PDFBox support for PDF creation is very low level, i.e. we don't support paragraphs or tables out of the box. There is no tutorial, but a lot of examples. The API orients itself on the PDF specification.

Comment: There still is a small bug in that font subsetting in the current SNAPSHOT: If on the same page you first use a font without subsetting (`stream.setFont(font, 12, false);`), then add some text, then use the same font with subsetting (`stream.setFont(font, 12, true);`), then add some more text, the text drawn up to the second font setting operation may be incomplete. (But as I saw other glitches in this context have recently been fixed, I think this also will be fixed soon.) ;)

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Apache PDFBox can't deal with Unicode, see:
    https://pdfbox.apache.org/ideas.html

iTextPdf v. 5.x generates pdf files with Unicode. There is an exemple here:
    iText in Action: Chapter 11: Choosing the right font
    part3.chapter11.UnicodeExample
    http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=199

To run it, you just need to adapt the value of EncodingExample.FONT and to add some code to create the output file.