# PDFBOX for Persian document

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, arabic, persian

I want to use **pdfBox** to extract test from *Persian* pdf files, but it returns `"?"` for all the Persian characters (it returns correctly the *Latin* words in the same document).

How can I  fix it? Any advice?

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133789/java-generate-unicode-pdf-with-apache-pdfbox)?

Comment: @deHaar the question you referenced is about *adding* text, not about *extracting* it.

Comment: @Azadeh where did you see the question marks? Output to a console? The console may not be able to display the glyphs in question. Otherwise please share the pdf in question.

Comment: See also https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction , please tell what happens when you copy + paste from Adobe Reader into editor.

Comment: @mkl   I get dots or question marks for every single Persian character, and yes I check the results in console.and copy paste from adobe reader works well. here is a link to a sample document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/olonkte03wi6ucp/t2.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  copy paste from adobe reader works well

Comment: Well it didn't work for me. I didn't get any persian text. The persian text is vector graphics, not text from fonts. If you got persian text, then maybe there is a new version of Adobe Reader that does OCR.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you :) I have one more question, do you think if it is possible to remove all the text from this file and only keep the images ( using pdfBox)?

Comment: Try the RemoveAllText.java from the source code download, in the example subproject. Also here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/RemoveAllText.java?view=markup

Comment: @TilmanHausherr,  Thank you I was able to remove the text. Back to my first question I did the test you suggested for my files. For  the files that I can extract text in Acrobat  I still get the "?" for persian glyphs I also get the following warning:org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font toUnicode
WARNING: No Unicode mapping for CID+1127 (1127) in font PIOACI+Arial-BoldMT
 I need to add that the text I get from Acrobat is in wrong order (left to write) but I don't get even this in eclipse. And hers is a sample file:https://www.dropbox.com/s/qc71qu7hlyw7e29/sample2.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I ran ExtractText on that file and get quite a lot of what I assume is persian, e.g. "فهرست مطالب", "شماره صفحه", "كليات -فصل دوم". The warning is about one single glyph that doesn't have Unicode. I can't tell easily which one it is. What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: The glyph without Unicode is a rectangular bullet point on page 102.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  I upgraded my pdfbpx from 2.0.9 to 2.0.11 and now I can extract the Persian words thanks.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am going to extract text form about 10000 files...I was wondering if there is any automated way to recognize if a pdf file is a text from font or not.  I was wondering if pdfbox can provide such property of the file? Thanks

Comment: No, one would have to make an analysis of the  PDF content stream and then make a decision with heuristics. It would be tricky - how to decide if curves are from a font or from a graphic? And sometimes files are mixed, i.e. both fonts and vector graphics that paint glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the provided file has the persian text as vector graphics, not as text from fonts, so it cannot be extracted. You'll have to use OCR for it.

See also the [text extraction FAQ](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction):

> How come I am not getting any text from the PDF document?
>
> Text extraction from a pdf document is a complicated task and there
>   are many factors involved that effect the possibility and accuracy of
>   text extraction. It would be helpful to the PDFBox team if you could
>   try a couple things.
>
> Open the PDF in Acrobat and try to extract text from there. If Acrobat
>   can extract text then PDFBox should be able to as well and it is a bug
>   if it cannot. If Acrobat cannot extract text then PDFBox ‘probably’
>   cannot either.
>
> It might really be an image instead of text. Some PDF documents are
>   just images that have been scanned in. You can tell by using the
>   selection tool in Acrobat, if you can’t select any text then it is
>   probably an image.